# How to fix "Task 'build' not found in root project 'genie-voucher-module'"

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build, build.gradle

I checked out newly created Spring boot project from the Git. it is a Gradle project.
Im using Intellij Idea as my editor. after open the project i hit gradle build on the terminal. So it gives build Fails

**What went wrong:**
`Task 'build' not found in root project 'genie-voucher-module'.`

**What I have tried so far:**
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace.
Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get.

How to fix this?

Comment: Which project are you talking about? If you can’t point to it, then please at least provide a [mcve].

Comment: Improved general question formatting, highlighted headlines and code/console text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens because of importing wrong project module.so that IDE cannot identify the place where necessary files located to build the project. please check it and upload the correct one.